# REST service doesnt take partial URI

Tags: java, rest

I have a requirement where need to put version in request URI to hit the respective service.
For ex: if path is like : localhost:8080/context-root/rest/v1/company

then this service can be hit with below URLs:
localhost:8080/context-root/rest/v1/company
localhost:8080/context-root/rest/company

To achieve this in rest service filter I am adding v1 in case second URL is hit.
It is working fine when I was using jersey 1.8 with servlet com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet

But when I am using jersey 2.4 with servlet org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer it is not working, it is not able to hit the filter altogether since there is no path for /rest/company. v1 was getting added in filter.

I was thinking if partial URL(up to /rest) can be hit and in filter I will change the request url for correct path.

Working web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.abc.ws.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>        
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.abc.filters.RestServiceFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Not working web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.abc.ws.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>        
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>com.abc.filter.RestServiceFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Working one is hitting the filter class even /rest/company URL is hit, whereas not working one is not hitting filter for same url

REST endpoint class:

```
    @Path("/v1/company")
public class CompanyRestService {
}
```

Updated pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm-all-repackaged</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

RestServiceFilter code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils;

public class RestServiceFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(RestServiceFilter.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext crc)  {

        _logger.info("***** REST FILTER*********************");
        crc = updateURLForVersion(crc);
    }

    private ContainerRequestContext updateURLForVersion(ContainerRequestContext cr) {
        String baseURI = cr.getUriInfo().getBaseUri().toString();
        String requestURI = cr.getUriInfo().getRequestUri().toString();
        String pathURI = requestURI.substring(baseURI.length(), requestURI.length());
        String version = null;
        if (pathURI.startsWith("v") && pathURI.contains("/")) {
            String versionInURL = pathURI.substring(1, pathURI.indexOf("/"));
            if (NumberUtils.isNumber(versionInURL)) {
                version = "v" + versionInURL;
            }
        }
        if (StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(version)) {
            version = ConfigReader.getinstance().get(Constants.REST_LATEST_VERSION);
            pathURI = version + "/" + pathURI;
            requestURI = baseURI + pathURI;
            try {
                cr.getUriInfo().getRequestUriBuilder().replacePath(requestURI);
//            cr.setRequestUri(new URI(requestURI));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Logger.getLogger(RestServiceFilter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return cr;
    }
```

Comment: Can we see the code ?

Comment: Please refer the original post for code

Comment: If I remember, you don't need to use a web.xml with jersey 2, you have to create a class which inherit ResourceConfig

Comment: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.4/deployment.html

Comment: your param-name is wrong. please use that javax.ws.rs.Application instead of  jersey.config.server.provider.packages

Answer (score 0):

I think that's your problem :

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.abc.ws.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        ...
    </servlet>
```

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.4/deployment.html

Comment: This also didnt work. Created own application class extending ResourceConfig.

Comment: For /rest/company the RestServiceFitler is not at all invoked to correct and append the version in requested URL

Comment: Have you change your jar ? Please add also the rest endpoint class

Comment: Added endpoint class header and pom.xml for reference to jars

Comment: Have you changed the param-name ? Because that's code works for me

Comment: Yes, I changed it. Can you please share your web.xml, Application class and endpoint class path used

Comment: Added RestServiceFilter code, which adds version in request url in case not present. Your code is similar to mine, but still facing issue. Please let me know if you have tried by adding filter into it and see if partial request url hits the server.

Comment: I think ServletContainer (jersey - 2.4) restricts such partial url as there is lot of code there inside class, and I tried creating a custom class which extends ServletContainer, the request is going there but then it throws 404 error. Whereas for SpringServlet(jersey - 1.8) doesnt have that much restriction for url.